# WooCommerce Corrupted - Product Export csv

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv

My woo-commerce plugin has corrupted and there is no more Woo-commerce menu in my back-end wordpress navigation menu to edit, is there any possible way to export as csv file from the databases through PHPmyadmin, I am beginner, hence kindly suggest some steps to export as csv, so that I can import in Woo-commerce after re installation of the plugin. Also when I try to re-install Woo-commerce plugin it says "Installation failed: Destination folder already exists."

Comment: Using your hosting account's file manager (probably cPanel) navigate to /wp-content/plugins folder and rename woocommerce to woocommerce_old. Then try to reinstall it through wordpress' dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

you must need to take DB backup first and than replace woo commerce plugin folder in Wp-content this may resolve you woo commerce issue and your data will be safe